# SML/NJ windows installer

Tags: smlnj

Can anyone verify that the .msi works on Windows 10?  I have been downloading and trying different versions 110.75 - 78 with no success.  The installers will all start up but after you choose the install directory and hit install the following message appears:

> Error reading from file D:\Downloads\smlnj-110.78.msi. Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.  My user was the only user with privileges on the folder containing the .msi file. I added the SYSTEM user and it works and installs now.